# FreeBSD: man exits at EOF

Tags: freebsd, man, less

When using `man` to view manpages on FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p11 I get back to the command promt after scrolling to EOF. What I want: `man` should not quit when I reach the end of the manpage as I may want to scroll back up...

On Xubuntu that works well. Any tips on how to do that?

I read that the program `less` has the option `-E` to "quit-at-eof". Is it possible that `man` has this option turned on by default? If so I couldn't find any information on that on the manpage of `man`.

Comment: Does `echo $MANPAGER` show anything? Or `echo $LESS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information **is** on the manual page for `man`.  It's in the section on environment variables.

If neither `MANPAGER` nor `PAGER` exist in the environment, the `man` command behaves as follows.  If coloured manuals are requested, it invokes `less -sR`; otherwise it invokes `more -s`.

The behaviour of the `less` and `more` commands, in turn, is that `less` does not quit at end of file by default whereas `more` does.

So the simplest approach, which is what I do myself, is to turn coloured manuals on.  In my `~/.login_conf` I have (omitting some irrelevant environment variables):

```
me:\
    :setenv=MANWIDTH=tty,MANCOLOR=1,MANITALIC=1:\
    :hushlogin:
```

The `MANWIDTH` and `MANCOLOR` environment variables are documented in that same part of that same manual page.

The `MANITALIC` environment variable invokes a patch to `man` that I wrote that turns on `grotty`'s (already present) ability to generate italic ECMA-48 output, making all of the manual pages that are marked up with things like `.I` and `.BI` generate actual italic text on my screen.  My terminal supports italics.  If yours does too (and many do), you might like to try this.

`~/.login_conf` is FreeBSD's shell-agnostic way of setting environment variables for an interactive login session, by the way.  You can use your shell-specific mechanism, whatever your shell of choice is, if you like.  `man login.conf`.  ☺

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [*Italics and colour in manual pages on a nosh user-space virtual terminal*](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/italics-in-manuals.html).  The nosh package.
- https://superuser.com/questions/204743/

Comment: The `.login_conf`-trick didn't work, but I found out that $PAGER was set to "more". I set it to "less -sR" like you said and now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your very clear and detailed answer. :-) (Okay, I reread your answer and you already said that your trick only works if $PAGER and $MANPAGER aren't set. My bad.^^)